# Centering Text in a Flex Column when the text wraps?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a column with a logo at the top and text below the logo some text in a different container.  The css for the flex container is set to `flex flex-direction: column align-items: center`.  When the text does not wrap the layout looks like this:

```
              logo
         foo  boo0  foo
```

However if the container shrinks so that the text has to wrap this happens:

```
              logo
         foo  boo0  
         foo
```

Is there a CSS setting that would make it look like this:

```
              logo
           foo  boo0  
              foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-align: center`?

```css
.logo {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > div {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="logo">logo</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div>foofoofoofoofoofoofoo</div>
    <div>barbarbarbarbarbarbar</div>
    <div>bazbazbazbazbazbazbaz</div>
  </div>
</div>
```